# Binding TextBox IsEnabled to property of VM

Tags: wpf, mvvm

Here's the sanitized control hierarchy in my View, and its bindings (I wish SO wouldn't remove leading spaces!!!)...

UserControl

StackPanel

ListView  ItemsSource="{Binding LineItems}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedLineItem}"

GridView

GridViewColumn

GridViewColumn.CellTemplate

DataTemplate

TextBox Text="{Binding Description}"

---

LineItems and SelectedLineItem are properties in my ViewModel, **while Description is a property within the class referenced by SelectedLineItem.**

Now I need to enable/disable the TextBox based on a new "AllowEdit" property in my ViewModel (AllowEdit is NOT a propery of SelectedLineItem).

How do I bind the IsEnabled property of the TextBox to the AllowEdit property?

I've done the requisite reading, but it's not clear how to do this!

Thanks!

DadCat

Answer (score 2):

```
<TextBox IsEnabled="{Binding DataContext.AllowEdit, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}}"/>
```